# Getting the biggest subset under a certain limit?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Given a list of reals `A = [a1, a2, a3,..., an]` and a real `x`, is there a polynomial-time algorithm that gets a subset `b` of `A` such that:

- `sum(b) <= x`; and
- there does not exist another subset `c` of `A` such that `sum(c) <= x and sum(b) < sum(c)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RubenBermudez: It's not really a "welcome" to Stackoverflow with 2k reputation...

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: I don't think that this is a terrible question, given that the OP doesn't recognize what he's asking. It's very bad from a "gimme teh codez" perspective, but not from a "question about complexity theory" perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99% sure that this can't be done. This sounds like a restatement of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) -- or, at the very least, the knapsack problem can be reduced to this. Unless `P=NP`, you're out of luck.